# Value of Query string

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

How can i get the `total` value from the following URL `http://tradephonein.com/checkout-swap/?total=$18.00&broken=No&water=%20No&power=Yes,%20battery%20included&lcd=No&charger=&manual=Owner%20Manual&box=&other=`

I have this kind of a string query, you'll see that there is a `total=$18.00`, my question is, how can I get the value because I want it to subtract in a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those values are in your query then you can use the following

```
if( get_query_var('total') ) {
    $total_value = floatval( str_replace( '$', '', get_query_var('total') ) );
}
```

or else

```
if( isset( $_GET['total'] ) ) {
    $total_value = floatval( str_replace( '$', '', $_GET['total'] ) );
}
```

Comment: No isset check?

Comment: Yeah done the isset check :)

Comment: sorry I forgot to say thank you, thanks anyway. it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about gravity forms. But normally you get that value with php via $_GET / $_POST object / array:

```
<?php 
isset($total) ? $total : $total = 0; // is total set; if not set it to 0;
$total = substr($_GET['total'], "$"); // grab the value after the dollar sign
$total = strval(htmlentities($total)); // Let's sanitize the values. Don't forget to do this!
?>
```

Sorry i haven't actually test that yet.

Comment: No isset check?

Comment: Just demonstrating concepts. But good point. I'll add it in for you @t31os

Comment: You already had my +1 anyway, but i'd give you another if i could for adding that in.. :) Further note, might wanna cast that value to int... (never know what that value may contain)..